# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Tags: spring, postgresql, datasource

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'xaDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xaDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'xaDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource]: Bean property 'driverClassName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1980)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">

```
<bean id="requestHandler" class="org.dejach.marketServer.requesthandler.RequestHandler"  init-method="init">
    <property name="factory" ref="marketApiFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="RequestProcessor" class="org.dejach.marketServer.processor.RequestProcessor">
    <property name="handler" ref="requestHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="marketApiFactory" class="org.dejach.marketServer.processor.MarketApiFactory">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>WEB-INF/marketApi.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="nullValue" value="@null" />
</bean>

<bean id="properties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="WEB-INF/marketApi.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource">
    <!-- <property name="pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection" value="true" /> -->
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbcUrl}" />
    <property name="user" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />

</bean>

<!-- configure an Atomikos JTA-aware datasource -->
<bean id="xaDataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="xaDatasource" />
    <property name="xaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="poolSize" value="${poolSize}" />
</bean>

<!-- http://fogbugz.atomikos.com/default.asp?community.6.702.5 -->
<bean id="userTransactionService" class="com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdownForce">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name">${com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name}</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir">${com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir}</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout">3600000</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close" depends-on="userTransactionService">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
    <property name="startupTransactionService" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="${transactionTimeout}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
    depends-on="atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="${showSql}" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${databasePlatform}" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="${generateDdl}" />
    <property name="database" value="${database}" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="xaDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="${marketPackage}" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendor" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

```
username=postgres
password=$$$$$$$
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# package scan for entities
marketPackage=org.dejach
transactionTimeout=300
showSql=true
#databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#database=org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database.MYSQL
#database=MYSQL
database=POSTGRESQL
generateDdl=false
poolSize=30
#XA datasource
#XADataSource=${mysqlDataSource}
XADataSource=${postgresqlDataSource}
#mysqlDataSource=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource
postgresqlDataSource=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
H2xadatasource=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
postgresqlUrl = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ethiopianMarketdb
H2url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
jdbcUrl=${postgresqlUrl}
blobFieldName=xmlData
#Atomikus properties
#see http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties                                                                 com.atomikos.icatch.service=com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory


com.atomikos.icatch.console_file_name

#Specifies the console log level. Defaults to WARN. Should be one of: WARN,  INFO or DEBUG.
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name=tmlog
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir=target
#com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir=/transactionLogs/
#com.atomikos.icatch.tm_unique_name=
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=3600000
```

Comment: `Invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource]: Bean property 'driverClassName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method`. It makes no sense to tell to a Postgres datasource which driver it should use.

Comment: @JB Nizet I have tried it with out that line. I added that later. In both cases the same error. Assume it is not there! Thanks.

Comment: I can't assume it's not here, since the error message precisely tells that THAT is the problem. Remove it, and if there is **another** error message, then **read** it, and post it if you can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a setter **setDriverClassName(..)** in following class

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/xa/PGXADataSource.html

So, it make sense to remove following property from **xaDataSource** and try once again

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
```

BTW, I don't any setUrl either, so you should review the logic of creating your bean.

Here is the list of available setters:

- setCompatible
- setDatabaseName
- setLoginTimeout
- setLogLevel
- setLogWriter
- **setPassword**
- setPortNumber
- setPrepareThreshold
- setProtocolVersion
- setServerName
- setSocketTimeout
- setSsl
- setSslfactory
- setTcpKeepAlive
- setUnknownLength
- **setUser**
- writeBaseObject

Comment: Thankyou, your answer has helped me change my datasource bean definition but I still have another error. Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V

Comment: I found out that this specific problem is related to a malformation of relation between entities in the model and now the problem is gone. Thanks!